Discriminated union over instance attributes
Suppose I have the following class
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.attr1: Union[Attr11, Attr12]
        self.attr2: Literal["val1", "val2", "val3"]
        self.attr3: Attr3
        ...
        self.attrn: Attrn

I am interested in the following type hint:
if self.attr2 == "val1":
    # self.attr1 should be Attr11 here
else:
    # self.attr1 should be Attr12 here

How can I do it?

I am interested in what exactly is the question here

You can do this with pydantic discriminated unions.

Is it possible without a third-party library? @larsks

There is nothing like a native type hint for specifying a discriminated union.

You should probably be using subclassing, where subclasses of MyClass represent the value otherwise assigned to attr2, and the type of attr1 varies from one subclass to another. Or make MyClass generic, so that something like MyClass(attr2="val1") has type MyClass[Attr1] and MyClass(attr2="val2") has type MyClass[Attr2].

(It's not clear you can take the generic approach without making attr2 itself be a value of the appropriate type, as Python lacks type-level mappings of values to types.)

In python desire to use such discriminated unions usually indicates insufficient segregation. One of the (sometimes) appropriate solutions would be to merge attr1 and attr2 into a single type and narrow with isinstance, and there are other options, but relying on "attribute foo is Y, so attribute bar is X" is very error-prone and often results in spaghetti code, difficult to understand and maintain.
